# Django project: within AJAX, parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, ajax, django

I am working on building a Django project.
Once the button is clicked, the form will be submitted and some tasks will be performed based on the information from  the form. However, in my case, the task can be done properly while there is always error pop up saying: "parsererror  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".

Here is my AJAX function:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#productForm', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'product/',
        data: {
          region: $("#Region-choice").val(),
          country: $("#Country-choice").val(),
          product: $("#Product-choice").val(),
          dvn: $("#dvn").val(),
          reship: $("#reshipCheckbox").val(),
          reshipId: $("#reshipTextfield").val(),
          validator: $("#Validator").val()}
        })
        .done(function(){
            alert("Product Created!");
        })
        .fail(function(req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Something went wrong!:" + textStatus + '  ' + errorThrown );
        });
    alert("Submitted!");
});
```

Views function:

```
def viewCreateProduct(request):
"""The .delay() call here is to convert the function to be called asynchronously"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    region = request.POST.get('region')
    country = request.POST.get('country')
    product = request.POST.get('product')
    dvn = request.POST.get('dvn')
    reship = request.POST.get('reship')
    reshipId = request.POST.get('reshipId')
    validator = request.POST.get('validator')

    task = createProduct.delay(region, country, product, dvn, reship, reshipId, validator)


    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Just to be clear: the alert from the `.fail()` condition is shown? In which case you need to look at what your Django view is returning, since obviously that's not valid JSON. Please look in your browser developer tools what is being return, and if that's not what you expect, please show us the Django view for `/product/` url

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, the alert from .fail()  is shown. And nothing is returned since I just need to triger the task in views.py. I have attached the views as well.

Comment: You need to return valid JSON, an empty string isn't valid JSON. Also to be sure, the content type you return should be `application/json` (not `text/html`). You can use the `JsonResponse` class instead of `HttpResponse` or set the content-type header of your `HttpResponse`. But main thing is: set the content to some valid JSON.

Comment: @dirkgroten yep, it is solved. Please add your comment in the answer and I will mark it as the solution. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you need to return valid JSON from your Django view:

- An empty string isn't valid JSON, so make sure your response has valid JSON as its body
- Also (although probably not critical in this case) you should set the Content-Type header to `application/json` instead of `text/html` which is the default for an `HttpResponse`. You can use Django's `JsonResponse` instead or add the correct HTTP header to your `HttpResponse` object.